# Mysql temporary table for different users

Tags: mysql

Is there any table type that can only be accessed by a particular user?
This table can only be viewed and accessed only by the user who created it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

But you can create a table that has user created column so you can use it on your where condition.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong. Yes you can set user specific access for particular table. Its syntax is as follow

```
GRANT SELECT ON db2.invoice TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
```

Temporary tables are available under particular session and not accessible by any other session. It will be dropped on session close.

For more information read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html

Comment: how about using temporary table?is it unique for each user?

Comment: @user3782464 [in the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html): _A TEMPORARY table is visible only to the current session, and is dropped automatically when the session is closed. This means that two different sessions can use the same temporary table name without conflicting with each other._

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is **Yes**

You can set privileges for that particular table like who can access that table. Like,

`SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE,` .

I have tried in via phpmyadmin.